# Django Error On Delete Option in Admin Page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model with information about products. I can delete objects by running the following code.

```
Items.objects.get(id=3).delete()
```

However, when I delete from the admin area, I run into a strange error for some products (but not all).

The exception I get is

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type MyUser)
Exception Location: /opt/python/run/venv/lib/python3.4/site-   packages/django/utils/encoding.py in force_text, line 90
```

I've tried removing all of my overwritten **str** methods, and nothing has changed.

The (MyUser type) is my custom implementation of the User in django which I've basically taken directly from the docs.

The traceback shows the local variable "seen" with value "Error in formatting: TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type MyUser)" in the following function call

```
roots.extend(self._nested(root, seen, format_callback))
```

It looks like this is called while creating the tree like structure on the **confirm delete page**. I'm almost positive none of my **str** methods return a MyUser object...

Comment: Did you run 'python manage.py makemigrations' and 'python manage.py migrate' ?

Comment: Yes. I just checked and no migrations are available. The exception is only raised on very few products. I have a database of about 2k products and so far have only found a handful where this occurs.

Comment: Did you define 'AUTH_USER _MODEL' in your settings.py? And everywhere you import it, you used  'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'?  Please try to add to your question the source code where it failed. (Models, views)

Comment: Interesting. I have a COMPLETELY unrelated app called "member" where I handle user registration which had a messed up __str__ method returning a MyUser objects. I just fixed it, and my issue is gone. But why was this __str__ method getting called for some objects and not others? Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind, I know exactly why... a feature which i discontinued allowed users to add items to their backend. These added items were saved to a model under the user. This model return a MyUser on __str__. Items that were added previously were still around, thats why these very few completely random items had the issue. Thank you for you help, the second part of your question helped me find it lol.